# how do i prevent my WiFi to be disconnected when laptop goes to sleep

Tags: wireless

In Ubuntu 15.04, the WiFi connection gets disconnected every time I put my computer to sleep and takes time to connect when I resume.

how do I prevent my WiFi to be disconnected when laptop goes to sleep?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Can you have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) and post more information?

Answer (score 0):

When you "put my computer on sleep" do mean Hibernate or Suspend? Either one removes power from the WiFi hardware, which is set to its initial power-on state on restoration. Unless you're command-line-literate, and willing to read `man` pages, and look at the `pm-utils` package, you will have to continue to wait for (how much time did you say? Seconds, Minutes or Hours?).